# hosted IronPython: possible to get currently executed source line?

Tags: debugging, ironpython

Is it possible to retrieve the line number from a Python script that is being executed within a hosted IronPython environment? I would like to somehow highlight that line in an AvalonEdit control outside of the hosted environment (in the hosting application that is) while the script is being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out, it is possible to get the line by simply giving the script engine a trace callback method and (maybe asynchronously) fire an appropriate event that accordingly refreshes a IBackgroundRenderer... well... it works.

```
strategyScriptEngine.SetTrace(IronPythonTraceBack);
strategyScriptEngine.Execute(script, strategyScope);
```

At some other place in the same class:

```
private static TracebackDelegate IronPythonTraceBack(TraceBackFrame frame, string result, object payload)
{
    if (IronPythonExecutingLine != null) IronPythonExecutingLine((int)frame.f_lineno);
    return IronPythonTraceBack;
}
```